# How to retrieve id along with name when selected in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a select field that populates data as below. I populate data items as their names. My goal is to select data's name and their corresponded ids. 
Here is my HTML template:

```
<select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="test" [(ngModel)]="record.firstName" #firstName="ngModel" name="firstName">
    <option value="">Choose...</option>
    <option *ngFor="let item of items" value="{{ item.name}}">{{ item.name }}</option>
</select>
```

When I select an item from the dropdown, `record.firstName` is set to `item.name` as expected. I was wondering how can I also retrieve `item.id` when I select the same item. I couldn't find a resource or tutorials to fix this. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of setting the option values to `item.name`, you can set them to the `item` objects with `[ngValue]`. That will allow you to access any property of the selected item. If necessary, you can handle the `ngModelChange` event to do additional processing.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedItem" (ngModelChange)="processSelectedItem($event)" ...>
    <option [ngValue]="undefined">Choose...</option>
    <option *ngFor="let item of items" [ngValue]="item">{{ item.name }}</option>
</select>
```

As an example, you could set `record` to a modified version of the selected item with:

```
processSelectedItem(item) {
    this.record.firstName = item.name;
    this.record.item_id = item.id;
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could bind the options to `item.id` (I assume that the `id` is unique), and set the `record.firstName` in the `ngModelChange` event handler:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="record.item_id" (ngModelChange)="processSelectedItem($event)" ...>
    <option value="-1">Choose...</option>
    <option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item.id">{{ item.name }}</option>
</select>
```

with:

```
processSelectedItem(itemId) {
    this.record.firstName = this.items.find(x => x.id === itemId).name;
}
```

Comment: When I  do this, I get {"selectedItem":{"id":15, "name":"test"}}. Is there any way to get as {"name":"test", "tem_id":15}?

Comment: I added an example of `processSelectedItem`, where you can process the selected item as you want.

Comment: And I added an alternative solution, more similar to your original code. I bound the value to the `id` (this is more usual, since the `id` is unique), but you could bind the `name` and set `record.item_id` in `processSelectedItem`.